# Center Text in Parallax Cover (Firewatch Parallax in CSS)

Tags: css, center, parallax, text-align

Many of you probably know the Firewatch Parallax in CSS pen by Sam Beckham, which recreates the parallax effect of the Firewatch website: https://codepen.io/samdbeckham/pen/OPXPNp

```
<div class="parallax__cover">
```

I want to put some text in this div to close out the parallax effect and I can't figure out how to center this text in my viewport.

Problem is, the surrounding div "parallax" is much wider than the viewport and it starts 1500 px to the left of it.

Any ideas?

I tried to center it the usual ways with an auto-margin etc. I expected the text to be horizontally centered but that does not work.